# Default size of results window SQL Server Management Studio or alternative

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, application-settings

Any one who uses SQL Server 2008, or earlier variants, knows that when you run the commands in the window the results window pops up for the lower half of the screen. I do want to see my results but when only the first or top 10 results will do have the window is a waste. Is there a way I can change the default size of that window?

Also if this kind of functionality exists in VS 2008 or 2010 let me know and I'll abandon SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to change the default size of the results pane. You may want to try sending your results to a separate tab instead. You can adjust this setting for both Results to Grid and Results to Text.

Under the Tools -> Options menu:
[image]
[image]

Comment: There could not possibly be a more perfect solution to what I was looking to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Grid Results

[image]

Comment: this should be the current answer

Comment: This is just the font size, not the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use this:

```
set rowcount 10
```

And you will only get the first 10 lines of your result.

Comment: I hoped it could be that easy. I want a way to set the size of the results window not just number of rows in the results.

Comment: Then I just do not understand your question. My results pane is fixed and comes up with a scrollbar if there are a lot of results.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the OP is wanting to save screen real-estate by having the Results window take up less space.

Answer (score 0):

It's the second time that I'm searching for an answer to the exact same irritant and although the results tab, proposed by Joe Stefanelli, isn't a bad option, I found the actual way to fix this.

I'm on SSM 2017 and all you have to do is pop your query out of your SSMS interface. In other words, say your SSMS is open on your primary screen, you click on 'New Query', a 'SQLQuery1.sql' window opens, then u click and drag that tab out of SSMS on your secondary screen.
From then on, after rolling your first query, simply adjust the results pane to the desired size and it'll remain at that size the next time you execute.

You're welcome! <(^-^<)

Comment: You don't need to drag the tab out to do this. Once the results pane has been manually readjusted it'll stay the same height in that tab.